# How to change the keyboard input type on Android

Tags: android, textinput

I know that when using a **EditText** we can change the input type using the `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);` method. But, I'm not using a EditText, I'm showing the keyboard using the `imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)`, getting the input values on the onKey event and showing them in a TextView for specific reasons. :)

There's some way to change the input type through the **InputMethodManager**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite weird, I can only think two workarounds:

1. You can try to use an invisible EditText and try if this gets the InputType
2. You could replace your TextView by an EditText, and then overwrite the style of this EditText with a custom one.

Comment: I create a custom keyboard, for other reasons, but your method seems to work. :)